# add single kanji characters

Tags: sphinx, japanese

I am a little lost adding a few (<10) kanji characters to my document.

I am using current sphinx and mactex installations. The document builds fine using `DeclareUnicodeCharacter` statements in the preamble. Unfortunately I could not find/google the right way to to the mapping to include the kanji characters in the tex/pdf output.

```
\\usepackage{CJK}
\\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{5E7D}{}
%\\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{5E7D}{\\UTF{5E7D}}  % does not work
```

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: if it's really just 10 it's probably easiest just to include them as images.

Comment: not convinced because this would most likely break the sphinx html output (which currently works just fine)

Comment: I don't know what sphinx does here but does it understand the mapping of kanji to 8bit fonts as required by pdftex, I'd guess that you just want that unicode slots to pass straight through in html (which could be arranged even if using images in pdftex) or if you can use luatex  or xetex rather than pdftex you can simply use unicode fonts everywhere.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I forgot to mention in my question that the html part of sphinx does work fine. For configurations in the latex part the conf.py file allows to configure a preamble. I am convinced the easiest would be to do the declaration `\\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{5E7D}{xxx_here_xxx}` right. The installations you suggested I would like to avoid I already installed two latex distributions last week.

Comment: Ok although all standard tex distributions include lualatex and xelatex by default so if you have a recently installed tex system you should have xelatex unless you specifically opted out (cjk has to go to a lot of work mapping the entire character set into multiple fonts with 256 characters each, it works but seems massively overkill to get 10 characters)

Answer (score 4):

Really I think it doesn't make sense any more to typeset these large scripts with fonts restricted to 256 characters per font, xelatex and lualatex can both handle Unicode OpenType fonts directly.

However this typesets the needed character in pdflatex, producing

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}

a\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}幽\end{CJK*}b

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I understand that this is not a sphinx compatible solution. The customization needs to go into the preamble. Is there a way to put "\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}幽\end{CJK*}" into `DeclareUnicodeCharacter`?

Comment: inputenc and cjk are separately decoding the utf8 input so you need to switch somewhere but anyway you need to switch fonts don't you? if you defined \newcommand\textcjk[1]{\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}#1\end{CJK*}` then it would look like `a\textcjk{幽}b` which isn't so different from `a\textbf{x}b` ? (otherwise you'd have to decode what CJKutf8 package is generating for 幽 and then declare that as the value of the utf8/inputenc declaration of 幽